# How to change background color of input based on entered value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I'm trying to change the background color of an input field based on the value entered. I have some JS that details some greater than/less than conditions.

**Question** - It is only working in the first cell and not all the rest. How do I get the script to pass through the other input values?

**HTML snippet:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 text-center">
        <label for="k-cls" class="text-strong">CLS</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="k-cls" placeholder="#" onchange="checkFilled();">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Here's the JS snippet:**

```
function checkFilled() {
    var inputVal = document.getElementById("k-cls");
    if (inputVal.value >= 6 && inputVal.value <= 9) {
        inputVal.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
    else{
        inputVal.style.backgroundColor = "";
    }
}        
checkFilled();
```

Here's a current working **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/newnam/pen/wXpKRG)**.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique and you're duplicating them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you cannot have multiple elements on one page with the same ID - so you should make sure to fix that. Classes are fine to be reused. Read more about the differences between ID and class [at CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/).

Second, this can be accomplished agnostic of an element's ID/class/etc. by simply passing a reference of the `onchange` event to your function, as seen below.

(I've also swapped onchange out for `onkeyup` so you can see the function run immediately.)

EDIT: Per discussion in the comments below, additional functionality has been added to this demo.

```js
function checkFilled(event) {
  var inputVal = event.target;
  var inputData = JSON.parse(inputVal.dataset.ranges);
  var color = "";

  for (i = 0; i < inputData.length; i++) {
    if (inputVal.value >= inputData[i][0] && inputVal.value <= inputData[i][1]) {
      color = inputData[i][2];
      break;
    }
  }

  inputVal.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```html
<input 
  placeholder="#"
  data-ranges='[[1, 3, "yellow"], [4, 6, "blue"], [7, 9, "red"]]'
  onkeyup="checkFilled(event);">
```

Comment: Ultimately, each one of the columns will be different. k-cls, k-wwr, etc... each will have different background color based on the input values. I've updated the codepen **[here](https://codepen.io/newnam/pen/wXpKRG)**. I'm trying implement what you're suggesting, but I'm not seeing it yet.

Comment: @webfrogs Just saw your response. I've updated my answer showing how to accomplish this with a single function and data attributes on the HTML elements.

Comment: This is one solution I've already come to. What I'm confused on is how to associate the different values and colors. For example (and I'm keeping things simple for both of us), if k-cls is between 1 - 3, then it's yellow. If k-cls is between 4 - 6, then blue. If k-cls is between 7 - 9, then it's red.

Does that make sense? Each range needs a different color. This is where I'm stuck.

Comment: @webfrogs You keep moving the goalpost! I'm happy to help, but would appreciate if you mark my answer as having solved your original question.

Comment: Done. and apologies. You're help is greatly appreciated. I've got half the battle... just need help getting to the goal post.

Comment: @webfrogs I've updated my answer with a new solution. It takes a multidimensional array on the element's data attribute consisting of any number of ranges that are formatted like `[min, max, color]` and iterates through them to see if the input falls between them. Hope this solves your issue!